# SQL Server Tricky Inserts

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-insert

So I have a couple of tables I am loading in the database from a "Staging" table using SQL Server 2012. The staging table looks like this:

```
-- tbl_staging
Id  Latitude  Longitude  Date       Veg_Type  Canopy
----------------------------------------------------
1   1.22      2.33       12/20/2015 Grass     Open
2   2.22      3.15       12/20/2015 Forest    Closed
... ....      ....       ....       ....      ....
```

The intent is to use this table to load data into 2 other tables in the database

```
-- tbl_SurveyDataRows
Id    Latitude    Longitude    SurvDate
-----------------------------------------
1     1.22        2.33         12/20/2015
2     2.22        3.15         12/20/2015
...   ....        ....         ....

-- tbl_SurveyData (This is a pivoted version of the above table)
Id    SurveyDataRowId    Value
-------------------------------
1     1                  Grass -- value for vegetation type 
2     1                  Open  -- value for canopy cover
3     2                  Forest -- value for vegetation type
4     2                  Closed --this is the value for canopy for the second row in Staging table
```

Loading the `tbl_SurveyDataRows` table is straightforward, as I just have to do a select:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_SurveyDataRows(Latitude, Longitude, SurveyDate)
SELECT Latitude, Longitude, Date
FROM tbl_staging
```

But how do I insert the corresponding data into the `tbl_SurveyData` table?

Comment: the `tbl_SurveyData` seems to be missing at least one column?. I mean, how would you know if the row is for `vegetation`  or `canopy`?

Comment: Is tbl_SurveyDataRows.Id an IDENTITY column?

Comment: O yes, it is an Identity column.